# Making Different combinations from a string that has been seperated

Tags: java

I am trying to make different combinations of a full name that has been broken down to different names. My code is as below :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Username {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
          System.out.println("Please enter a Firstname , MiddleName & Lastname separated by spaces");
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          String name = sc.nextLine();
          String[] arr = name.split(" ");
          int arrLength = arr.length;
          //for(int i = 0; i <= arrLength - 1; i++)
          //{
             // System.out.println("Name" + i + " " +  arr[arrLength-(arrLength-i)] + "\n");
         // }
          if(arrLength == 2)
          {
              System.out.println("Name length is 2");
              String Name1 = arr[arrLength-arrLength];
              String Name2 = arr[arrLength-(arrLength-1)];
              String firstLetterName1 = String.valueOf(Name1.charAt(0));
              String firstLetterName2 = String.valueOf(Name2.charAt(0));
              String windowsUsername1 = Name1 + "" + firstLetterName2.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername2 = Name2 + "" + firstLetterName1.toUpperCase();
              System.out.println("Username1 " + windowsUsername1);
              System.out.println("Username2 " + windowsUsername2);
          }
          if(arrLength == 3)
          {
              System.out.println("Name length is 3");
              String Name1 = arr[arrLength-arrLength];
              String Name2 = arr[arrLength-(arrLength-1)];
              String Name3 = arr[arrLength-(arrLength-2)];
              String firstLetterName1 = String.valueOf(Name1.charAt(0));
              String firstLetterName2 = String.valueOf(Name2.charAt(0));
              String firstLetterName3 = String.valueOf(Name3.charAt(0));
              String windowsUsername1 = Name1 + "" + firstLetterName2.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername2 = Name1 + "" + firstLetterName3.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername3 = Name2 + "" + firstLetterName1.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername4 = Name2 + "" + firstLetterName3.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername5 = Name3 + "" + firstLetterName1.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername6 = Name3 + "" + firstLetterName2.toUpperCase();
              System.out.println("Windows Usernames are " + windowsUsername1 + " " + windowsUsername2 + " " + windowsUsername3 + " "
                                + windowsUsername4 + " " + windowsUsername5 + " " + windowsUsername6);
          }
          if(arrLength == 4)
          {
              System.out.println("Name length is 4");
              String Name1 = arr[arrLength-arrLength];
              String Name2 = arr[arrLength-(arrLength-1)];
              String Name3 = arr[arrLength-(arrLength-2)];
              String Name4 = arr[arrLength-(arrLength-3)];
              String firstLetterName1 = String.valueOf(Name1.charAt(0));
              String firstLetterName2 = String.valueOf(Name2.charAt(0));
              String firstLetterName3 = String.valueOf(Name3.charAt(0));
              String firstLetterName4 = String.valueOf(Name4.charAt(0));
              String windowsUsername1 = Name1 + "" + firstLetterName2.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername2 = Name1 + "" + firstLetterName3.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername3 = Name1 + "" + firstLetterName4.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername4 = Name2 + "" + firstLetterName1.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername5 = Name2 + "" + firstLetterName3.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername6 = Name2 + "" + firstLetterName4.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername7 = Name3 + "" + firstLetterName1.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername8 = Name3 + "" + firstLetterName2.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername9 = Name3 + "" + firstLetterName4.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername10 = Name4 + "" + firstLetterName1.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername11 = Name4 + "" + firstLetterName2.toUpperCase();
              String windowsUsername12 = Name4 + "" + firstLetterName3.toUpperCase();
              System.out.println("Windows Usernames are " + windowsUsername1 + " " + windowsUsername2 + " " + windowsUsername3 + " "
                    + windowsUsername4 + " " + windowsUsername5 + " " + windowsUsername6 + " " 
                      + windowsUsername7 + " " + windowsUsername8 + " " + windowsUsername9 + " " + windowsUsername10 + " " + windowsUsername11
                      + " " + windowsUsername12 );
          }
    }   
}
```

Test output is below :

> **Please enter a Firstname , MiddleName & Lastname separated by spaces**
>     *Maria Anna Sophia Cecilia* 
>   Name length is 4 
>   **Windows Usernames are**
>     MariaA  MariaS  MariaC Anna  AnnaS AnnaC Sophia  SophiaA SophiaC
>   Cecilia    CeciliaA CeciliaS

I found this code very untidy though and in effective too. Are they any better ways of doing this? Yet an amateur and struggling with concepts from Java. Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Can you give an example as well? I don't understand how you form combinations, is it all permutations of the names that are given?

Comment: @RobAu yes, they are just permutations of the names that are given. I shall add an example too.

Comment: I think in your code username cannot be just 'Anna'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Java naming conventions

In Java variables should never start with a capital, so rename `Name` to `name`

### Input validation

What about empty input? Or a name with length 1? Make sure you can handle all input.

### Logic

I would try to do something like this:

- Create a `List<String>` of names
- Maybe remove duplicates?
- For each item in the list, capitalize the first letter
- Create all permutations of length 2 of this list (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323560/461499)
- For each permutation, create the output by taking the first item of the `List<String>`, and append the first letter of the second.

### Example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Names {

    private static List<List<String>> generate(List<List<String>> permutations, List<String> names, int length) {

        List<List<String>> perms = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        if (length == 0) {
            perms.add(new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            for (String name : names) {
                // copy names, but leave out the current
                List<String> namesWithoutCurrent = new ArrayList<>(names);
                namesWithoutCurrent.remove(name);
                for (List<String> perm : generate(permutations, namesWithoutCurrent, length - 1)) {
                    perm.add(name);
                    perms.add(perm);
                }
            }
        }
        return perms;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (List<String> perm : generate(null, Arrays.asList("Anna", "Maria", "Sophia", "Cecilia"), 2)) {
            System.out.println("Windows username:" + perm.get(0) + perm.get(1).charAt(0));
        } 

    }
}
```

> ```
> Windows username:MariaA
> Windows username:SophiaA
> Windows username:CeciliaA
> Windows username:AnnaM
> Windows username:SophiaM
> Windows username:CeciliaM
> Windows username:AnnaS
> Windows username:MariaS
> Windows username:CeciliaS
> Windows username:AnnaC
> Windows username:MariaC
> Windows username:SophiaC
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Could you possibly give a small example?